# SQL simple query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL question.

I have 3 tables

```
Books
--------------------
Book_ID(pk) | Title | Price
--------------------

Clients
---------------------
Client_ID(pk) | Name |

CardsOfReaders
---------------------
Book_ID(pk,fk)| Client_ID(pk, fk)
```

So the question is: How to display the name of the reader who borrowed the book with the highest price (and the column price to be displayed as well)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select top 1 c.name, b.price
from books b
inner join cardsofcreaders cr on cr.book_id = b.book_id
inner join clients c on c.client_id = cr.client_id
order by b.price desc
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking a slightly different spin on your question, given your table structure, note that it is possible for multiple clients to borrow the book with the most expensive price. To find all such clients:

```
SELECT c.Name, b.Price
FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 Book_ID, Price
    FROM BOOKS
    ORDER BY Price desc
  ) b
  INNER JOIN CardsOfReaders car
  on b.BOOK_ID = car.BOOK_ID
  INNER JOIN Clients c
  ON car.ClientID = c.Client_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or yet another variation, since in real life many books may have the same, highest price.

```
SELECT C.name, B.Price --,B.Title /*In case there are several books*/
FROM (SELECT MAX(Price) MPrice
   FROM BOOKS) mx
JOIN BOOKS B ON B.Price = mx.MPrice
JOIN CardsOfReaders crd ON crd.BOOK_ID = B.BOOK_ID
JOIN Clients C on C.ClientID = crd.ClientID
```